# Android how to get 'getCurrentInputConnection()' from which is not extended from InputMethodService

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I think my question title is enough to say what problem I'm facing now. I've made a class that implements InputMethodService, I started this service, then I called the InputConnection value from my Activity, but always get null value. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score -1):

you can find answer in this line

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/generating-keypresses-programmatically.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.